# How to get mapDispatchToProps method to dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React/Redux and programming in general.  Below is my code between 3 files.  I am passing the store to a Provider that wraps my React-Router.  The problem is in 1), I know getTweets runs and actions are imported properly because testing() runs no problem.  But the debugger in fetchAllTweets under actions is never hit.  Can any of you veterans please tell me what my issue might be?

1)    Relevant container code:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import Feed from './feed';
    import {fetchAllTweets, testing} from '../../actions/tweet_actions';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
        getTweets: () => {
            testing();
            return dispatch(fetchAllTweets);
        }
    });

    const FeedContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Feed);

    export default FeedContainer;
```

2) Relevant actions code

```
import * as APIUtil from '../util/tweet_api_util';
import Constants from '../constants/constants';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const fetchAllTweets = () => dispatch => {
    debugger;
    console.log('fetch all tweets action');
    APIUtil.fetchAllTweets()
        .then(tweets => dispatch(receiveTweets(tweets))), 
        err => dispatch(receiveErrors(err.responseJSON))
};

export const testing = () => {
    debugger;
    console.log("worked");
}
```

3) Store code

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import RootReducer from '../reducers/root_reducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const configureStore = (preloadedState = {}) => (
  createStore(
    RootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
)

export default configureStore;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass value returned by `fetchAllTweets` action creator as `dispatch` argument, not the action creator function itself.

Use this:

```
return dispatch(fetchAllTweets());
```

instead of this:

```
return dispatch(fetchAllTweets);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) and use it in your container as following:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import Feed from './feed';
import { tweetActions } from '../../actions/tweet_actions';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(tweetActions, dispatch);
});

const FeedContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Feed);

export default FeedContainer;
```

Then in your component just call them as `this.props.actions.fetchAllTweets()` and `this.props.actions.test()`

Comment: It is a good practice. This helps you to keep your redux logic inside your container, meaning your component will be cleaner and will only need to call those actions from it's props.